# Custom Tag Librarys JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tags, taglib, custom-tags

So I have a custom tag that currently works, but I would like to change it from the current date to show the date and the current time.

this is what I have as an output  `Current Date/Time: Monday, March 31, 2014`

### This is my tag

```
<%@ tag language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ tag import="java.util.Date" import="java.text.DateFormat"%>

<%
    DateFormat dateFormat = 
            DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);
    Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    out.println(dateFormat.format(now));

%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the time as well use the `getDateTimeInstance()` method or for more flexibility use the SimpleDateFromat

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

By the way, the Date constructor `new Date ()` will obtain the current date, you do not need to pass `System.currentTimeMillis()`